# jersey-client throws NPE in ClientResponse.getLastModified()

Tags: java, rest, jersey, rest-client

I use jersey-client to consume a REST service.
I need both the requested Entity and the Last-Modified header.

So I do the following:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);
Person person = response.getEntity(Person.class);
```

That works. I get a response and I can marshal the Entity (wich is XML) into my POJO.
When I debug and take a look into the Headers of the response, then I see that there is a Last-Modified header set.

But when I try to retrieve the date via

```
response.getLastModified();
```

I get a NPE somewhere in URLConnectionClientHandler.

Has anyone a clue what I do wrong?

**edit:** as requested the trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getLastModified(ClientResponse.java:647) ~[jersey-client-1.12.jar:1.12]
at a.o.u.user.dao.impl.uds.PersonenUdsClient.getPerson(PersonenUdsClient.java:103) ~[um-user-2.5.0-Beta1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at a.o.u.user.dao.impl.UserDaoUdsImpl.mergeWithUdsUser(UserDaoUdsImpl.java:282) ~[um-user-2.5.0-Beta1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at a.o.u.user.dao.impl.UserDaoUdsImpl.getUserWithEmail(UserDaoUdsImpl.java:124) ~[um-user-2.5.0-Beta1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ...
```

**edit:** as npe suggested I digged into the code. I think I found the problem. Beside jersey-client I also have cxf in the classpath. Both jersey and cxf provide a class called *RuntimeDelegateImpl*. But CXFs version does not feature a DateHeaderDelegate. I think the wrong version (CXFs) of *RuntimeDelegateImpl* is taken.

By now I have not found how I can explicitely set the *RuntimeDelegateImpl* to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a wrap.

The problem is that I have both jersey-client and cxf in the classpath. Both RuntimeDelegateImpl. But CXFs version does not feature a DateHeaderDelegate. The wrong version (CXFs) of RuntimeDelegateImpl is taken.

I solved the issue by retrieving the Last-Modified Header 'manually':

```
private Date getLastModified(ClientResponse response){
    String lastModifiedString = response.getHeaders().getFirst(
            "Last-Modified");
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(lastModifiedString)) {
        LOG.warn("Expect to get Last-Modified header when retrieving a Person by pnr "
                + "but there is none.");
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            // format is Thu, 21 Jun 2012 08:00:42 GMT
            return new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US)
                    .parse(lastModifiedString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOG.error("Could not parse Last-Modified date "
                    + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanx to npe for the hints.

Answer (score 2):

[*Use the source, Luke*](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.12/jersey-client-1.12-sources.jar)

The implementation of `ClientResponse#getLastModified()` for version 1.12 looks like this:

```
/*639*/  /**
/*640*/   * Get the last modified date.
/*641*/   *
/*642*/   * @return the last modified date, otherwise <code>null</code> if not present.
/*643*/   */
/*644*/  public Date getLastModified() {
/*645*/      String d = getHeaders().getFirst("Last-Modified");
/*646*/  
/*647*/      return (d != null) ? dateDelegate.fromString(d) : null;
/*648*/  }
```

You get a `NullPointerException` in line 647, so it appears, that `dateDelegate` is `null`. Now, the `dateDelegate` object is initialized in line 321, like this:

```
/*321*/  protected static final HeaderDelegate<Date> dateDelegate =
/*322*/          RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createHeaderDelegate(Date.class);
```

Now, the field is `final`, so it cannot be changed after this initialization - which means `dateDelegate` is `null` from the beginning - and that means, **you have some kind of configuration issue** and the delegate is not created.

Further, delegates are created in the `AbstractRuntimeDelegate` class ([source for 1.12 here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.12/jersey-core-1.12-sources.jar)), like this:

```
/* 88*/  map.put(Date.class, _createHeaderDelegate(Date.class));
```

This rabbit hole goes deeper and deeper, so I'm going to stop here, but you know the way.

And last, but not least - debugger is your friend, my friend ;-)

Comment: true, the source is always usefull. But I thought a thing like the dateDelate should just be there, without me doing something special. I looks quite fundamental to me. Is my init code incorrect?

I init my client with Client.create(); and then I get my WebResource like this getClient().resource(baseUrl);

I could also use ClientConfig for creating the client, but there is nothing in there that seesm to be related with the dateDelegate.

Comment: Well, if you dig deeper, you'll find that there is a `com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider` file in the `jersey-core.jar` `META-INF/services` folder that is used to define the delegates. Unless you're doing something with those JARs (like removing `META-INF`), I really have no clue why it's not loaded. I think you need to debug Jersey's initialization code I've pointed you to, to find out.